# Argument type bytes4 is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) bytes4[] calldata

Tags: solidity

I have the below small piece of code:

```
  bytes4[] internal stateFunctions;
  mapping(bytes32 => bytes4) internal stateFunction;

  function addAllowedFunctionForState(bytes32 state, bytes4 allowedFunction) public doesStateExist(state) {
    if (!knownSelector[allowedFunction]) {
      stateFunction[state] = allowedFunction;
      stateFunctions.push(allowedFunction);
    }
    states[state].allowedFunctions[allowedFunction] = true;
  }

 function stateChecker(bytes32 state) public view returns
    (bytes4[] calldata allowedFunctions)
    {
    return stateFunction[state];
   
    }
```

What I would like it to return is all the allowedFunction for a specific state in the function stateChecker. I am a rooky to solidity so I am a bit confused with the title error. If you guys could have a look, it would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return `bytes4`  but return type is declared as `bytes4[]`

```
function stateChecker(bytes32 state) public view returns
(bytes4[] calldata allowedFunctions)
{
    return stateFunction[state];
}
```

if `bytes4[]` be changed to `bytes4` hopefully it should work!